# Sorting an array

Tags: php, sorting, arrayobject

If I have an array of data, what is the best option for sorting them so they are displayed in ascending alphabetical order based on key 2 of the second array within each ArrayObject?

Data

```
ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
   'job_category_filter_population' => 
  ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
     10225 => 
    ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
       0 => 
      array (
        0 => '10042',
        1 => 'Root',
      ),
       1 => 
      array (
        0 => '10225',
        1 => 'Supply',
      ),
    )),
     10228 => 
    ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
       0 => 
      array (
        0 => '10042',
        1 => 'Root',
      ),
       1 => 
      array (
        0 => '10228',
        1 => 'X-ray',
      ),
    )),
     10226 => 
    ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
       0 => 
      array (
        0 => '10042',
        1 => 'Root',
      ),
       1 => 
      array (
        0 => '10226',
        1 => 'Team',
      ),
    ))
  ))
))
```

E.g. Supply, Team and then X-ray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would use [`ArrayObject::uasort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.uasort.php) and provide a callback function that compares the second element of the second array of its arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a quick look but I#m not entirely sure what is passed to the function cmp. What is $a and what is $b?

Comment: `$a` and `$b` are two items from the array that need to be compared. Because you have a multidimensional array you need to access your comparable values like so `$a[0]` and `$b[0]`. Although this could be wrong as your array is hard to follow in its current format.

Comment: I don't see how using this will allow me to sort the array according to ascending alphabetical order.

Comment: The comparison function is provided with two elements from the array, and should return whether the first element should be placed before or after the second element in the final order.

Answer (score 1):

Look at using `usort()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php